# Unity Prefab spawn incorrect rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I have the following simple prefab:

[image]

When I add this to my scene, it looks like this:

[image]

Very neat!

Then I have the following script on my Character:

```
public class MageController : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject Spell;
    public float SpellSpeed;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H)) {
            GameObject newSpell = Instantiate(Spell);
            newSpell.transform.position = transform.position;
            newSpell.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, transform.up);
            Rigidbody rb = newSpell.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            rb.AddForce(newSpell.transform.forward * SpellSpeed);
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is of course to make sure that the `fireball` is spawned correctly (with the tail behind it)

This works when I stand at `0.0.0`; it looks like this:

[image]

However, if I turn around it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the rotation of the fireball is not correct (in the above incorrect image it is flying away from me, however, the tail is in front).

What am I doing wrong? How can I make sure that the tail is always correctly placed?

**Update after following the guidance of PlantProgrammer**
it still turns incorrectly :(

Look at the image below!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the forward direction of the player and not it's rotation, when instantiating the fireball. (Remember: **transform** in your script is the player transform not the fireball transform.) Check https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html. LookRotation will return the rotation based on player's forward and up vectors.

```
GameObject newSpell = Instantiate(Spell);
newSpell.transform.position = transform.position;
newSpell.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(transform.forward, transform.up);
```

Not part of your question, but I would also suggest letting the fireball fly in the forward direction of itself not the player (as this leaves more room for later modifications)

```
rb.AddForce(newSpell.transform.forward * SpellSpeed);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but isnt it newSpell.transform.position = transform.position?

Comment: Yes, of course it is :) I just didn't pay enough attention. I edited it, now.

Comment: Could you add the hierarchy of the spell prefab and the player GameObject?